# Why longtable adds vertical skip after head on subsequent pages and how to fix this?

Tags: longtable

Why longtable adds vertical skip after head on subsequent pages and how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,margin=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{rp{8cm}}
\caption{Example table}
\\\toprule
\textbf{P} & \textbf{Text}
\\\toprule
\endfirsthead

\caption[]{Example table (continued)}
\\\toprule
\textbf{P} & \textbf{Text}
\\\toprule
\endhead

\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize continued on the next page}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & \lipsum[1]\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\\*\midrule
2 & \lipsum[2]\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\\*\midrule
3 & \lipsum[3]\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\\*\midrule
4 & \lipsum[4]\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\end{longtable}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, color=red, line width=0.2pt]
\draw ([yshift=-18.9mm]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-18.9mm]current page.north east);
\draw ([yshift=-19.9mm]current page.north west) -- ([yshift=-19.9mm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Above document and images of its pages clearly show the problem (I've used TikZ to stress it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the space after a `\midrule`; you can cancel it by introducing an explicit `\addlinespace`:

```
\begin{longtable}{rp{8cm}}
\caption{Example table}
\\\toprule
\textbf{P} & \textbf{Text}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\endfirsthead

\caption[]{Example table (continued)}
\\\toprule
\textbf{P} & \textbf{Text}
\\\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\addlinespace[0pt]
\endhead

\multicolumn{2}{r}{\footnotesize continued on the next page}
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & \lipsum*[1]
\\\midrule
2 & \lipsum*[2]
\\\midrule
3 & \lipsum*[3]
\\\midrule
4 & \lipsum*[4]
\end{longtable}
```

Notice that `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]` is preferable to a `\toprule` in that position; `\lipsum*` avoids a final `\par` command, so that it's not necessary to backspace.

Comment: +1 Thank you! Adding `\addlinespace[0pt]` in head fixes the problem. Other remarks are also useful.